# RATE() is returning "#NUM!"

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, worksheet-function

I am trying to calculate the rate of an annuity that costs $100,000 and pays $50,000 per year for 23 years. I am entering this into Excel as:

```
=RATE(23, 50000, -100000)
```

but this results in:

```
#NUM!
```

What am I doing wrong? The cell is a percentage, and I am entering the numbers in manually. I am using Excel (Mac) 2007.

Comment: What format is the cell in?

Comment: @blackmind: The RATE() cell is a percentage.

Comment: Are you pulling the numbers from other fields?

Comment: No, I'm entering the numbers in manually.

Comment: try this http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/441002.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [If the successive results of RATE do not converge to within 0.0000001 after 20 iterations, RATE returns the #NUM! error value.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/rate-HP005209232.aspx)

Without including a guess for the Guess it is assumed to be 10 percent and that is nowhere near the actual rate that would be required to equate $100k now to $50k pa for 23 years.

Try:

```
=RATE(23,50000,-100000,,,0.4)
```

and then either:

```
=RATE(23,50000,-100000,,,0.45)
```

or

```
=RATE(23,50000,-100000,,,0.6)
```